# IE8 returns “object doesn't support this property or method” when I use the equalHeights jQuery plug-in

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I'm getting a "object doesn't support this property or method" error in IE8 on my webpage and was just wondering if anyone could see anything wrong with the following code that it is flagging it up on:

```
excerptWrapper.equalHeights().find('.position_excerpt').css({display:'block', opacity:0, position:'absolute'});
var excerptWrapperHeight = excerptWrapper.height();
```

Comment: When you have `alert(excerptWrapper.equalHeights)` what do you see? Maybe *equalHeights* is defined but something further that code is not..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either:

- `excerptWrapper` is not a jQuery object. I.e. it wasn't created with `$(somethingHere)`.
- jQuery is not loaded.
- The equalHeights plugin is not loaded.
- If your equalHeights plugin isn't the one I found [here](http://www.cssnewbie.com/download/jquery.equalheights.js), then it may not return the jQuery object after it executes, therefore the rest of the statement is invalid.